# OAuth2 do not get the access token

Tags: paw-app

I configured an Authorization Dynamic value. All is correct but when I clicked the "Get the access token" button.

The access token is not copied in the token input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDhiA.png)

And all requests with the authentication are failed.

But if I copied manually the access token, all requests works.

What is the problem ?

I reinstalled the application without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are aware of some issues with the OAuth2 integration in Paw 3.2 which we aim to fix in the following weeks. Try to install the previous release http://paw.cloud/download/3.1.10 which should help here.

Please accept our apologies for any inconvenience caused!

- The Paw Team

Comment: Anything on this? It's been close to a month already.